# PHP Sorting through a form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which displays information from a MYSQL Database.

**Database Table**
[image]

I made a form which has the sorting options

**Form**

```
<form action= "properties.php" method="post" name="SortingForm">

            <label for="SortBy">Sort by</label>
            <select name="SortBy">
                  <option value="Added">Date Added</option>
                  <option value="Location">Location</option>
                  <option value="Type">Type</option>
                  <option value="Price">Price</option>
            </select>

             <input type="radio" name="SortingOrder" value="Ascending" checked> Ascending
             <input type="radio" name="SortingOrder" value="Descending"> Descending<br>

        </form>
```

This is how PHP displays the information by default

**Output**

```
<?php
        require("connect.php");

        //Linking
        $link = connectToDB();

        //SQL Query
        $sql = "SELECT tbl_property.propertyid,tbl_property.imagename,tbl_property.locationid,tbl_property.typeid,tbl_property.price,
                             tbl_town.townname,
                             tbl_type.typename
                  FROM tbl_property,tbl_town,tbl_type
                  WHERE tbl_town.townid = tbl_property.locationid AND tbl_type.typeid = tbl_property.typeid";

        //Execute
        $result = $link->query($sql);

            //Table Start
            echo "<table class='table'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Picture</th>";
                    echo "<th>Location</th>";
                    echo "<th>Type</th>";
                    echo "<th>Price</th>";
                    echo "<th>More Information</th>";
                        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){     
                        echo "<th>Edit Property</th>";
                        echo "<th>Delete Property</th>";
                        }
                echo "</tr>";

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        //Image Name
                        $ImageGetter = "images/".$row['imagename'];
                        //Information

                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo '<td><img height="150" width="200"" src="'.$ImageGetter.'" /></td>';
                                echo "<td>".$row['townname']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['typename']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>&euro;".$row['price']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>"."<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$row['propertyid']."\"> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>More Info</button></a>"."</td>";

                                        //If user is logged in, give extra buttons
                                        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){     
                                            echo "<td>"."<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</button>"."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"."<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['propertyid']."\"> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></a>"."</td>";
                                        }

                            echo "</tr>";

                    }
            echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

My question is, would it be possible to make the information shown from the database change from the sorting options chosen from the form, and if so, how? because I can't figure it out. Keep in mind that the showing does work, everything on the page shows correctly, but it is ordered by oldest to newest.

Comment: have you tried anything with  your `<select name="SortBy">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ORDER BY](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sorting-results.htm) at the end of your statement to sort your rows in a certain manner.

For example: `select ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY propertyid DESC` would sort your rows from the highest by propertyid to the lowest propertyid.

Comment: that's what I had in mind but I don't know how to execute it through my form

Comment: I'm not sure of your expertise in web design, do you know JQuery or such?

Comment: I don't know jquery but I do know javascript and how to use the POST method with PHP

Comment: Okay, so the best way for you then would be to use [Prepared Statments](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).... this way you could actually send the sorting value to your properties.php when you submit the form. EDIT: also using prepared statements is A LOT better as it prevents my SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll look into these as I haven't learned them yet

Comment: This answer only covers the ordering and not how to use their `<select name="SortBy">`.

Comment: No problem mate, they're an absolute must-have in PHP in my opinion as you will need them to have a fully secure website and it also gives more flexibility.

Comment: Fred -ii- I'd of guessed MarsBars9459 does know the POST method, but yes if you do want to get the selected SortBy option, you use the $_POST function, so your code would be `$option = $_POST['sortBy'];`. (edited to clarify)

Comment: @MinistryofChaps You missed the @ symbol here as I just did for you here. I only saw this comment above by revisiting the question and the OP didn't respond to my comment under the question, nor did they accept your answer. Oh well, *"c'est la vie"*, I guess.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the heads up mate! _c'est la vie_ indeed!